# Hide nodes on Mousedown in d3

Tags: javascript, jquery, d3.js

I have an HTML file that reads a JSON graph file and displays in the browser

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<style>

.node {
  stroke: #fff;
  stroke-width: 1.5px;
}

.link {
  stroke: #999;
  stroke-opacity: .6;
}

</style>
<body>
<script src="//d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
<script>

var width = 1280,
    height = 960;

var color = d3.scale.category20();

var force = d3.layout.force()
    .charge(-120)
    .linkDistance(30)
    .size([width, height]);

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height);

d3.json("data.json", function(error, graph) {
  if (error) throw error;

  force
      .nodes(graph.nodes)
      .links(graph.links)
      .start();

  var link = svg.selectAll(".link")
      .data(graph.links)
    .enter().append("line")
      .attr("class", "link")
      .style("stroke-width", function(d) { return Math.sqrt(d.value); });

  var node = svg.selectAll(".node")
      .data(graph.nodes)
    .enter().append("circle")
      .attr("class", "node")
      .attr("r", 5)
      .style("fill", function(d) { return color(d.fill); })
      .call(force.drag);

  node.append("title")
      .text(function(d) { return d.id; });

  force.on("tick", function() {
    link.attr("x1", function(d) { return d.source.x; })
        .attr("y1", function(d) { return d.source.y; })
        .attr("x2", function(d) { return d.target.x; })
        .attr("y2", function(d) { return d.target.y; });

    node.attr("cx", function(d) { return d.x; })
        .attr("cy", function(d) { return d.y; });
  });
});

</script>
```

I have an attribute for each node called `clique_nodes` which is a list of nodes that need to displayed on mousedown (hide every other node in the graph on mousedown). How do I do this?

Comment: where will be the mousedown function trigger? On nodes or on svg?

Comment: @echonax : mousedown on a node.. Each node has a list of nodes. All the other nodes and edges must be hidden on mousedown over that particular node

Comment: what do you mean by each node has a list of nodes? as child nodes?

Comment: @echonax `clique_nodes` is the key, a list of nodes is the value. these nodes will be connected to this node having `clique_node` key

Comment: @echonax : example `"clique_node":[1,2,3]`. Also, on mouseup, the nodes which were hidden must become visible again

Comment: so I can get this clique_node key from the handlers? like d.clique_node will give me the array. And the values are the index of nodes? as in 1 represents the first node in the node array?

Comment: @echonax `1` is the id of the node. its just a unique name to identify a node. Its not the first element in the node array in json

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/108027/discussion-between-echonax-and-prateek-narendra).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should attach 'mousedown' event handler to your nodes where you filter the "clique_node" attribute and make their opacity 0.

```
var gnodes = svg.selectAll('g.gnode')
 .data(graph.nodes)
 .enter()
 .append('g')
 .classed('gnode', true)
 .attr('clique_node', function(d,i){
     if(d.attr === "clique_node"){
            return true;
     }
 })
 .on("mousedown", function(d,i){
     d3.selectAll('.gnode').filter(function(d) {
         if(d.attr !== "clique_node"){return d;}
     })
     .attr("opacity",0);

     d3.selectAll('.link').filter(function(d) {
        if(d.source.attr !== "clique_node" || d.target.attr !== "clique_node"){return d;}
     })
     .attr("opacity",0);
 });
```

See the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/mcm3p2e9/1/